# Setting different preprocessor defines per source file in bazel cc_library

Tags: c++, bazel, bazel-cpp

I'm trying to write bazel rules for a 3rd party library that specify different pre-processor define values per file i.e.

```
c++ ... -DVALUE=file1.cpp -c file1.cpp
c++ ... -DVALUE=file2.cpp -c file2.cpp
c++ ... -DVALUE=file3.cpp -c file3.cpp
```

This is basically `set_property()` on the file to add `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` in `CMake`.

Using `copts` or `local_defines` for `cc_library()` doesn't seem to support this use case as they are common for all source files in the library.

The terrible ways to do this that I can think of:

- have a private library per file and consolidate all of them to one library.
- Patch the library or inject a header file using `-include` to add the definition.

Is there a better way to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Note: if the values given aren't just an example and you actually need the source filename as a preprocessor constant, you have `__FILE__` to your disposal.

Comment: The values are a bit of both. The filename is an extreme example of every compilation unit having a different value for a 3rd party lib I'm using. I completely agree that using `__FILE__` is the right thing to do but note that these are 3rd party libs and we try to avoid modifications when we can. I think the question is still valid when you have to deal with 3rd party libs.

Comment: If you're just trying to avoid modifications to the source files, you could generate wrapper `.cpp` files that define the macros and then `#include` the original ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach to that is to just make a separate `cc_library` for each file, and then aggregate them together. Bazel isn't actually going to create a separate `.a` file in most configurations, so it doesn't change very much. A [macro](https://bazel.build/extending/macros) or [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) may be helpful to avoid copy/paste for the attribute values shared between all of the `cc_libary` targets.

The other option is writing a custom rule. [my_c_compile](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_cc/blob/main/examples/my_c_compile/my_c_compile.bzl) and [my_c_archive](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_cc/blob/main/examples/my_c_archive/my_c_archive.bzl) are some basic examples, you could combine them pretty easily into a single rule that takes multiple source files and applies separate `user_compile_flags` to each. That seems like a lot of work though.

Bazel also includes a full implementation of `cc_library` in Starlark which you could start from when writing a custom rule, but that's really complicated in many ways which you don't need. It's in [src/main/starlark/builtins_bzl/common/cc/cc_library.bzl](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/src/main/starlark/builtins_bzl/common/cc/cc_library.bzl).

Comment: This is what I was mentioning about creating one lib per source file. I'm going for the macro approach for now until I find a better solution. Thanks.